# How do I turn a popup window into a tab in Chrome on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, chromecast

This is driving me nuts. I used to be able to cast my pluralsight videos using Chromecast by turning the pop up into a tab when I was using Chrome on Windows. I can't figure out how to do this on mac yet.

If I can't do it this way, then how can I cast a popup? I tried creating a keyboard shortcut but it did not work on the popup, only on a tabbed page.

Answer (score 13):

This was recently added to Chrome for Mac.

With a popup window in the foreground, choose the 'Show As Tab' item in the 'Window' menu. (in the menubar)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue and I just figured it out- in the address / omni bar at the top of the popup window, there should be an icon that looks like a page located at the far left of the bar. you can drag and drop that page icon into an existing chrome window to create a tab. I don't know if it works for every type of webpage, but it worked on mine. it reloads the page, but it is definitely working fine. hope this helps!

Comment: It reloads page. In case of Google Hangout it makes page blank.

Comment: This is just copying the popup's URL into a new tab. Better than nothing but not the same as the feature available on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't currently available for Chrome on Mac, but [a comment in Nov '15 in the Chromium repo](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=43953#c39) suggests that this will be fixed in Chromium at some point.

No information on when this will be available in Chrome yet.